# Concrete Mathematics: Clarification about equation 2.20: intersection of set with its complement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

In Concrete Mathematics (Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik) equation 2.20 is

$$
\sum_{k\in K}a_k + \sum_{k \in K'}a_k = \sum_{k \in K \cap K'}a_k + \sum_{k \in K \cup K'}a_k
$$

Specifically $k \in K \cap K'$: I would have thought a set cannot interect with its complement? So the equation could just be

$$
\sum_{k\in K}a_k + \sum_{k \in K'} = \sum_{k \in K \cup K'}a_k
$$

I am sure the authors had a good reason to include the intersection RHS sum and I want to make sure I understand the point they're making.

Comment: The good reason is that $K'$ is not the complement of $K$, but just another set.

Comment: Oh I see! I shall read it again in a new light

Comment: To be more precise, $K$ and $K'$ are both subsets of some set $E$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Specifically, ‘$K$ and $K'$ are any sets of integers’ (from the sentence introducing the equation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As J.-E. Pin and Brian M. Scott pointed out in the comments this was due to me not properly reading the part where they say

> If $K$ and $K'$ are any sets of integers

Now it makes sense. I shall certainly endeavour to read more carefully in the future ☕